# Can't configure FindBugs, Checkstyle, or PMD in NetBeans

Tags: plugins, netbeans, checkstyle, findbugs, pmd

I am attempting to configure Checkstyle, PMD, and FindBugs in Netbeans 7.4.  I have installed all three using the Software Quality Environment update center:
(http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/sqe/lastStableBuild/artifact/build/full-sqe-updatecenter/updates.xml).

All three analyzers work fine, and I can use them to scan my code.  However, I cannot configure them, and the yellow non-existent "trailing whitespace" errors are hurting my brain.

I am following the tutorial here:
http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/08/configuring-sqe-plugins-in-netbeans-7.html

When it gets the step of **Project Properties -> Quality -> Checkstyle**, I only get the following sentence on the screen, for each plugin...

```
 "No Maven Checkstyle Plugin found.  Falling back to global settings."

 "No Maven FindBugs Plugin found.  Falling back to global settings."

 "No Maven PMD Plugin found.  Falling back to global settings."
```

Any ideas on how to configure these bad boys?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have 2 options:

- disable the plugin bugging you (you can disable for instance only PMD)
- disable certain warndings

To disable the whole plugin:

1. Go to Tools - Plugins - Installed(tab)
2. Click the 'Show details' checkbox
3. Mark the plugin (for examle PMD)
4. Deactivate

To configure the plugin:

1. Tools - Options - Quality(tab)
2. Here you can configure your plugins individually

Comment: That's not much good. PMD is useful, it's just giving too many useless warnings (i.e. in one project, I'm seeing over 1,300 "DD" and "DU" dataflow analysis warnings, but of the dataflow warnings I'm only really interested in "UR" which is much more likely to be a serious error). Disabling the entire plugin defeats the purpose, and I don't see a place to disable the individual warnings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Window -> Quality -> Quality Control Center
2. Select a project
3. Select any of PMD/FindBugs/Checkstyle
4. Go to Quality -> Code Defects -> Select any of Run of PMD/FindBugs/Checkstyle
   or
    Select the project and on right click select Quality -> Code Defects -> Select any of Run of PMD/FindBugs/Checkstyle